# (Windows 7)Bridge: (tap+wifi) -> ok, (tap+ethernet) -> dhcp is not working. What are possible problems?

Tags: windows-7, dhcp, openvpn, bridge

All this happen on win 7.
I set up the ovpn bridged connection with wifi+tap bridged, and it worked fine.
Now I need to make it use ethernet instead of wifi, but bridging of ethenet+tap has issues: the bridge adapter does not get the ip/mask/gateway from the dhcp.
Both ethernet and wifi are connected to the same network and get their ips fine when not bridged.
Since this is a remote machine, I can't do many risky experiments (because each failure requires assistance of the people on their side).

What shall I look at to find the possible problems? I googled a lot yesterday but found nothing useful.

Comment: Are you bridging the Ethernet adaptor that is currently connected to the existing network?

Comment: Yes, ethernet is connected. Wifi also was connected when I bridged it.